# Commons HttpClient getResponse takes very long 200 seconds

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I changed nothing in this method but suddenly it takes very long. The code example below produces this error.

**EDIT:** i extracted the method in a single java application and tried to load the file and i have the same timeout. The 3 or 4. time he goes through this loop HttpMethodBase:691 he stops for 500 seconds at my local pc and the thread is sleeping. After sleeping the next line is `outstream.close();`

```
while ((len = instream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
   outstream.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
```

**EDIT:** Here is the example code if you wanna try it at home :) (httpClient 3.1)

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;


public class TestLoadImage {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        byte[] image = loadPhotoFromUrl("https://fbcdn-sphotos-a.akamaihd.net/photos-ak-snc1/v2635/232/115/68310606562/n68310606562_2255479_948765.jpg");
        System.out.println(image.length);
    }

    private static class GetMethodIgnoringContentLength extends GetMethod {

        public GetMethodIgnoringContentLength(String uri) {
            super(uri);
        }

        @Override
        public long getResponseContentLength() {
            // ignores content-length header, fakes "not specified":
            return -1;
        }

    }
    public static byte[] loadPhotoFromUrl(String photoUrl) {
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.getParams().setBooleanParameter("http.connection.stalecheck", true);
        GetMethod get = new GetMethodIgnoringContentLength(photoUrl);

        try {
            int httpStatus = httpClient.executeMethod(get);
            if (httpStatus == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
                byte[] imageBytes = get.getResponseBody();
                if (imageBytes.length > 0) {
                    return imageBytes;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed: empty response/zero data");
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed: "+ httpStatus);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println( ioe);
        } finally {
            get.releaseConnection();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: could be a slow server or a bad network connection. Does the same URL load faster in a browser or with curl?

Comment: jeah its loading a facebook profile picture, in the browser its instant shown. The "break" shows after all the "hex" data from the image is shown in the log. i try at the moment to activate org.apache trace log where exactly he is doing is break.

Comment: And its the same server as in the past, and the other requests to facebook are in normal speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it with an update to HttpClient4.1 (and some refactoring required therefor). But if someone knows the reason in the example above i switch the correct answer.